# How do I solve: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux, mern

I am following a Redux tutorial, but I've been stuck at this error for a while.

I've tried looking up and using tactics on StackOverflow from people who suffered a similar problem, but none of them worked. I tried adjusting my code in my `index.js` and `App.js` to better target "artist." I also double-checked my syntax to make sure I was targeting everything properly, but nothing's working.

Can someone please help me understand where this error is coming from and how I can fix it?

If it helps, the link to the tutorial I am following is listed below. Step 8 is the part I'm stuck on in particular. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiLVAXlVYR0&t=3s

Also, here is my GitHub Repo, in case the code below isn't enough to explain the problem:
https://github.com/adimacci95/K-Profiles

**Artist-List.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class artistList extends Component {

    createArtistList() {
        return this.props.artist.map((artist) => {
            return (
                <div className="card" key={artist.id}>
                    Hello
                    <div className="card-image"> 
                        <img src={artist.img} alt={artist.stagename}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {this.createArtistList()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        artist: state.artist
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(artistList);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/navbar.js';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import artistList from './pages/ArtistList/artist-list.js';

const App = () => (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/artists" component={artistList}/>
          </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import allArtists from './reducers/reducers.js';

const store = createStore(allArtists);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, React-components `render` a single time before retrieving any data from the `redux-store/mapStateToProps`.

You are currently executing `.map()` over an array that does not yet exist. ie: no data has been collected from props yet.

In `createArtistList()`, you should validate that there is in fact data before calling `.map()`. Just run a check like:

```
createArtistList() {
    const artists = this.props.artist
    if(artists && artists.length > 0){
        return artists.map((artist) => {
              return (
                 <div className="card" key={artist.id}>
                    Hello
                    <div className="card-image"> 
                       <img src={artist.img} alt={artist.stagename}/>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             );
           }
    } else {
        return "Loading..."
    }
}
```

Comment: And you will receive error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` XD.
Change `artists.length > 0` to `artists && artists.length > 0`

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Thanks for the help, guys! I tried the method above but, for some reason, I got a new error which reads "TypeError: instance.render is not a function". Any idea as to what could be causing this?

Comment: @GalaXee95, there may be a few reasons. May you update your code please?

Comment: @Arseniy-II The updated code should be available now on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to write your `map` function inside `render`,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class artistList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {this.props.artist.length > 0 && this.props.artist.map((artist) => (
                    <div className="card" key={artist.id}>
                        Hello
                        <div className="card-image"> 
                            <img src={artist.img} alt={artist.stagename}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    );
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        artist: state.artist
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(artistList);
```

Another way is, if you want to use the function only, then use [implicit return](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html),

```
createArtistList() {
    if(this.props.artist.length > 0){
        return this.props.artist.map((artist) => (
                 <div className="card" key={artist.id}>
                    Hello
                    <div className="card-image"> 
                       <img src={artist.img} alt={artist.stagename}/>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             );
           )
    } else {
        return "Loading..."
    }
}
```